# Block access to link - Can Can Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do the following:
I have a page that filters records by users:

this is my controller:

```
def index
  if current_user.role? "producer"
    @ search = Victim.joins (: producer). where (: producers => {: email => current_user.email}.) search (params [: search])
    @ @ search.paginate victims = (: page => params [: page],: per_page => 10)
  elsif
    @ search = Victim.search (params [: search])
    @ @ search.paginate victims = (: page => params [: page],: per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

it can filter the index records pertaining only to the current user.
but if the current user enter the id of a record in navigated he can see the data of a record that does not contain e-mail of the current user. would like to know how to bypass this access and allow the current user to access the page "show" only the record containing your e-mail as was done in the "index".

I  anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your current `show` method, routes, or models:

```
def show
    if Branch.exists?(params[:id])
        @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
        @branches = Victim.where (:branch_id => @branch.id)
    else

    if @branch.nil? || @branch.email != current_user.email
        log_message = "Current User #{current_user.email} was blocked from viewing a branch "
        log_message += "owned by #{@branch.email}" if @branch
        log_message += "#{params[:id]} that does not exist" if @branch.nil?
        logger.warn log_message 
        redirect_to action: "index"
    else
        logger.debug "Current User #{current_user.email} was allowed to view a branch with the email #{@branch.email}"
    end
end
```

Basically, in your show method, all you have to do is validate that the user does indeed have permissions to see that record. If not, redirect them somewhere else

Comment: is as follows:
I have a table of "victim" and it contains the field "branch_id" ("model - victim" = belongs_to: branch)
I also have a table of "branch" which contains the field "email"
the current user has the same email that the "branch" ...

So I would like done: to open the "show" of the "victim" It is verified whether "branch.email equals" current_user.email "if not denied access.

tried that more did not work:        `@branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
       @branches = Victim.where (:branch_id => @branch.id)
       redirect_to 'index' if @branch.email != current_user.email`

Comment: @user2701007 How did it not work? Did you get an error message or did it allow users to view branches that they did not own? I updated the solution to do logging which should help you debug it

Comment: me this message appears  `Processing by VictimsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"973"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Branch with id=973):
app/controllers/victims_controller.rb:29:in `show'`

Comment: insert the code suggested, but the current user still accessing the record of the "victim" does not have the "banch.email = current_user.mail"

Comment: The error message you received - `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` - means that you are trying to `show` a branch ID that doesn't even exist, it has nothing to do with permissions. I added a check to the answer to make sure the branch ID exists first.